# Swift crash with release code

Tags: xcode, swift

Can anyone shed any light as to why the following code would crash in the release version of an Xcode 6 build but not in the debug version ?

Can I cast this as something to try and prevent this

```
// Check if iCloud is enabled
if let currentToken = NSFileManager.defaultManager().ubiquityIdentityToken {
    // The following line causes a crash in Release version 
    FLOG("  currentUbiquityIdentityToken is \(currentToken)")
```

EDIT:

More digging and the problem was caused by this code when the "DataModel" name had been changed to something else. I would have expected the "let modelURL = NSBundle." line to have thrown an exception but it does not. Seems it was just pure coincidence that the debugger was on the "FLOG(...)" line of code when the bad access exception gets thrown.

```
   lazy var managedObjectModel: NSManagedObjectModel = {
        // The managed object model for the application. This property is not optional. It is a fatal error for the application not to be able to find and load its model.
        let modelURL = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("DataModel", withExtension: "momd")!
        return NSManagedObjectModel(contentsOfURL: modelURL)!
        }()
```

Comment: what is `FLOG`? It looks like it does different levels of logging, and as that might do different things between release and debug this is a likely candidate for the problem.

Comment: Its just a wrapper for 'println'.  Seems the problem is elsewhere, see edit above.